# how to download setup of any software for ubuntu 13.10 on window xp

Tags: downloads

I am very new to Ubuntu and I am just a beginner.

I have an Ubuntu computer (13.10), without an internet connection.

On another computer (XP) I do have an internet connection, and I would like to know how I can download software for the Ubuntu computer and prepare it on a pendrive, so I can install it on the Ubuntu computer.

Please tell step by step how can do that.

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to unplug the Ethernet cable of the XP system an plug it to your Ubuntu machine to perform the update/upgrade/install, just the time needed for the installation.

Comment: @SylvainPineau I guess if his Ubuntu computer is on another location, his cable won't be long enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is a Debian and so uses Debian Installation packages ending with .deb extension. So Any well packaged deb will do it. But Downloading outside System repository poses danger security wise. So unless you know what you are doing, don't install anything, and unless you trust the source don't install their packages.

That being said here are sites you can get debs and are safe (to best of my knowledge)
http://packages.ubuntu.com/